# Unable to restore Sharepoint Site from backup

Tags: powershell, backup, restore

I have a Sharepoint site (2013), I need to move the site to a different server. I am using Powershell to create backup and restore. But getting the error in ULS log:

> "Could not deserialize site from c:\temp\sbdocs.bak .
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Schema version of backup
>   15.0.4667.1000 does not match current schema version 15.0.4569.1000     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Restore(String filename, Boolean
>   isADMode, Boolean& readOnlyMode, Boolean&
>   hadWriteLock) 0bfd4ae1-2d1c-48ac-9cdb-0004ea5665a4"
>
> Powershell Error: Restore-SPSite :
>   0x80070003 At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Restore-SPSite -Identity http://server/sites/SiteName "c:\temp\sbdocs...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:SPCmdletRestoreSite)
>   [Restore-SPSite], DirectoryNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreSite

I am running the cmdlet with Admin access, ran the configuration wizard, checked the backup file path etc but still no luck. I need to move the site immediately but stuck up with this error.

Answer (score 2):

Your backup is running on a farm with November 2014 Cumulative update ( 15.0.4667.1000 ) installed while the farm you are trying to restore the backup to is running only on Service Pack 1 ( ​​15.0.4569.1000 ).

Install the November 2014 CU to the environment you are trying to restore your backup to and then try again. You should only need to apply the November 2014 CU as this contains all the updates since the Service Pack 1.

You can check the SharePoint build numbers on this blog. 
[SharePoint 2013 Build Numbers](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346)

Comment: Tried the solution, still no luck ! :(

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier. But did you apply the november CU to all your servers in the farm and run the wizard afterwards so you can make sure that the farm is on the right version number afterwards? Are there any difference between the architecture of the 2 farms you are trying to move a backup between?